# Tools for creating interactive web apps for tablets/touch screens

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, html

I am a junior web dev, my experience focuses mostly on the front-end work with react. I have been approached by a friend of a friend and asked if I could help his company with building interactive apps for touch screen devices in museums or art exhibitions. My task would focus on using assets provided to me from building apps from them and providing interactivity. There are several examples he gave me:

- https://kolejnictwo.x25.pl/stacja_basznia/
- https://zg.x25.pl/budowa_komorki/index.html
- https://twierdza-torun.x25.pl/s12_1/

I am looking for advice what frameworks, libraries and other tools would be beneficial for me to take a look at in order to help me speed up work on such apps?

Answer (score 0):

If you know React why not use [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)?